# ZK session variable with a menu

Tags: java, session, session-variables, zk, zk-grid

I have an application in ZK providers in my database, and i have my DAO to return all the names of my database.

And i have this view in ZK:

```
<zk>
    <window id="Mnos" border="normal" mode="modal" width="320px"
        apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
        viewModel="@id('vm') @init('operator')">
        <listbox model="@load(vm.provider)" onClick="@command('provider', provider = each)"/>

    </window>
</zk>
```

I need that when a user do click in some provider, save a session variable to use in my application, because i have a crud of services and when i create a service i need create the service related with the provider that the user choose in the menu, and i need create workers and i need create a worker related with the provider that the user choose in the menu,

and i have this java class:

```
public class operator {

    Collection<String> provider = MnoDAO.getAllProvidersByName();

    public Collection<String> getMno() {
            return mno;
        }
    @Command
    public void provider(@BindingParam("provider") String provider){
        Messagebox.show("Hola ... "+mnoList);
    }

}
```

My main problem is that  `each` is always null, and second i do not know how can i save a sesion variable to use in all application, and this variable can be change when i select other provider.

Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

ZK provides a [`Session`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/Session.html) object, accessible through the [`Sessions`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/Sessions.html) static getters. This can be used from anywhere in the ZK life cycle (any ZK managed thread).

```
String name = "myCoolVariable";
MyObject originalValue = getMyCoolVariable();
Session session = Sessions.getCurrent();
session.setAttribute(name, originalValue);

...

if (session.hasAttribute(name)) {
    MyObject retrievedValue = (MyObject) session.getAttribute(name);
}
```